# Android webview admob - how to display an interstial ad with javascript interface?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, admob, ads

I'm trying to call a "displayAd()" function from my javascript. Here's a sample of my code:
MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //Inject WebAppInterface methods into Web page by having Interface name 'Android'
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://myWebSite.com");
    }

public class WebAppInterface{
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void doSomething1(){
                  …
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void doSomething2(){
                  …
    }

}
```

How can i use this class or another way to call my function for display the ad like i'm doing now with the others functions. It seems to be easy but like i'm a beginer, i don't know how to do it. Here's another example of how i'm calling them:

```
function example1(){
    Android.doSomething1();
 }
function example2(){
    Android.doSomething2();
 }
```

and finaly here's the example of the documentation:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

public class BannerExample extends Activity {

  private InterstitialAd interstitial;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

  }

  public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
      interstitial.show();
    }
  }
}
```